# MySQL .NET Connector 6.7.4

Tags: asp.net, mysql, database, visual-studio

I'm am unable to use MySQL Connector 6.7.4 with my local asp.net provider, a security message is being shown saying that it doesn't have the GAC security accesss, anyone know if there's any chance (like in on web.config) to make it work ?

I know that my local web hosting provider (called locaweb) uses a medium trust environment and refuses to make any changes on their server (such as adding mysql latest version to their GAC). Old version of the connector, such as 6.2.2 are working fine.

I've read several articles in the internet (such as http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-medium-trust.html) but it didn't make clear to me if the changes were in my application's web.config or in my hosting config (which they refuse).

Thanks,